# Sharing a variable between method overloads?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm a real newbie programmer and I'm trying to make an overload that will share a variable. Basically what I want to do is have a method with one overload that writes an integer value to a variable within it and another overload that simply returns that value.

Now I tried to do it like this:

```
private int GetQID(int qID)
    {
        int ID = qID;
    }    
private int GetQID()
    {
        return ID;
    }
```

This unfortunately, doesn't work because the second overload can't access the "ID" variable of the first overload. Is there any way without resorting to global variables, that I can do this?

Comment: Use fields and properties.

Comment: I've answered as best I can given the limited description, but it would really be useful if you could give a more practical example of what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: In your context, I think that `property` is the best choice compare to using 2 separate method. `get` statement will act as `GetQID()` and `set` statement will act as `GetQID(int qID)`. You can also perform some logical inside property before actually set/return value.

Comment: Okay here's the thing. I have a friend who is studying programming and he tells me that global variables are the devil and that I should try to avoid using them at all cost. What I want to do is basically set an integer value and then be able to retrieve that same value within the same class. 

As for what the code is for, well basically I am generating a random number from a method and it's important that I can use this number in a number of other methods later. I hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, local variables are purely local to the method in question. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you want any state which persists between method calls, you'll need a field, and probably expose it as a property.

```
private int id;
public int Id
{
    set
    {
        // Perform some validation?
        id = value;
    }
    get { return id; }
}
```

If you just want a property which is backed by a field with no other logic, then automatically implemented properties are useful:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Okay this is basically what I was looking for, but are you telling me that the 2nd code example will do exactly the same thing as the 2nd example if I just want to set & retrieve a value?

Comment: @user3205941: Assuming you meant "exactly the same thing as the 1st example", yes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not access local variables.

They are *allocated* inside method, you can't control where, how and when, because these decisions are made by compiler, thus you can't access them even via *dirty* tricks.

Regarding `global variables are evil`, you better ask your friend yourself what he means (he is right, but only to a certain extent). Because you have to use properties and fields in many classes and any class can suddenly become *globally* available if give its instance to everybody (or if it's a static class with static properties/fields, singleton).

In your requirements all you need is a normal *property* of the class (as others already answered): you can set value of it and read it after. But it is important how you going to use that class, because this is where it may become suddenly *bad*.

Comment: Well he wasn't very specific he just mentioned that using global variables wasn't good because they aren't "secure" and you won't create a "secure" program if you use them. Apparently in his school they aren't allowed to use global variables for their programming assignments.

Comment: *Aren't secure* is that what they can be accessed from any place, so you have dozens of places where you can break something down. In the property you can have *private setter* or *protected setter* to limit access scope. For *public* properties you can limit the scope by **not giving instance of the class** to everybody, but only to those who you trust.